# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when doing operation on NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, arrays, dataset, nsmutablearray, exc-bad-access

I currently trying to connect to a Webserver, and consuming a table from it. I have put the table into a NSMutable array (it's global), named it DataSet (I got this part working). However When I try to preform any type of operation on it (Example: count), it will give me a EXC_BAD_ACCESS. BTW I'm using xcode 4.2 with ARC, so it's not a memory management issue. Any suggestions?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"`url.com`"];
    NSData *jsonData =[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    if(jsonData)

    {
        xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData: jsonData];
        [xmlParser setDelegate: self];
        [xmlParser parse];
    }
    NSLog(@"This is Number of elements: %@",[DataSet count]); ///<----EXC_BAD_ACCESS

 ..... //// default stuff//.....
    }



-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{


    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"string"])
    {

        /// puts the data into Array luckyNumbers
        NSError *error;
        SBJsonParser *json = [[SBJsonParser new] init];
        DataSet = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        DataSet = [json objectWithString:soapResults error:&error];

      ///  NSLog(@"%@",DataSet); /// this works

    }
}
```

I'm not sure if I'm suppose to but, I read that I should use Diagnostics, so I turned on NSZombie objects, Malloc guard, and Malloc Stack. 
They said I should type this into the gdb console
info malloc-history  (*memorylocation*)

### However I don't know where to get the memory location of the problem. I would appreciate any help.

I couldn't get this to work, so I tried using and NSDictionary instead of NSArray and surprisingly it work! Here is my updated code for anyone who was wondering what I did.

- (void)viewDidLoad

{

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"url.com"];
NSData *jsonData =[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
DataSet = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
```

if(jsonData)
    {

```
    xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData: jsonData];
    [xmlParser setDelegate: self];
    [xmlParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:YES];
    [xmlParser parse];
}
NSLog(@"%@",DataSet.allKeys);
```

///// default stuff ///
    }
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName

{

```
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"string"])
{


    //NSLog(@"%@",DataSet);
    DataSet = [soapResults JSONValue];
    NSLog(@"%@",DataSet);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

1) In `viewDidLoad` add:

```
DataSet = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

2) In `-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName`

```
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"string"])
{
    NSError *error;
    SBJsonParser *json = [[SBJsonParser new] init];
    [DataSet addObject:[json objectWithString:soapResults error:&error]];
    [json release];
}
```

3) After that in `DataSet` all parsed objects will be stored

Comment: Nope didn't work :/ Same problem, and I'm using ARC, so I don't need to release json.